# Problematic filename returned as '.xml' but does not exist

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, lxml

```
import lxml.etree as ET
import os

# Select path of Annotations 
path = "/home/student/Documents/Dataset/Train/Annotation/"

# Search for each file under the path
for files in os.listdir(path):
    # open the files by appending the path with file name. Parse it and find root
    with open(path + files) as f:
        tree = ET.parse(f)
        root = tree.getroot()
        
        # Loop through the elements 
        for elem in root.getiterator():
            try:
                if elem.tag == 'name':
                    if elem.text == 'person':
                        print(files)
         
            except AttributeError:
                pass
```

Result:

```
.xml
.xml
.xml
```

Hello, I am writing a script to change the label name of a certain class from 'person' to 'head', within a folder of .xml files. I did a simple counter to account for the total number of labels and realized that 3 labels were not converted.

The changing label name code:

```
        # Replace labels
        if elem.tag == 'name':
            elem.text = elem.text.replace('person', 'head')
```

While troubleshooting, I tried to print the filenames but it returned me 3 files named '.xml'. After running some tests, i found that all 3 instances are pointing to the same file. However, I am unable to find this file anywhere in the folder. Any idea why the filename is read as only the extension? Thank you!

The file naming conventions are:

```
XXXX.xml
PartA_XXXXX.xml
PartB_XXXXX.xml
```

Comment: Usually files starting with `.` on linux are hidden. Try running `ls -la` on the folder to show those files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is probably a file named `.xml` on this folder, but, by default files starting with `.` are hidden on linux.

If you run `ls -la` on the folder, you may see those files.

Regarding the fact that it printed `.xml` 3 times, it is probably because this file has the tag `name` set to `person` three times, since you don't `break` from the iteration after finding the first match.